# Cscope query to find files

Tags: c, macos, cscope

I used below script to build cscope database in /usr/include directory
in Mac OSX.

```
find $PWD -name "*.[chxsS]" -o -name "*.ddl" > cscope.files
cscope -b -q
```

There are 3 files with `msg.h` in its name/path.

```
fmtmsg.h 
rpc/rpc_msg.h
sys/msg.h
```

Once the database is built, I can only find `fmtmsg.h` when searching for `msg.h` file (entered in `Find this file:` row). Cscope doesn't show other files in results.

When search entry is `sys/msg.h`, Cscope finds `sys/msg.h` file.

What changes should I do to get all 3 results when searching for `msg.h` file?